# How to write do not print in pseudocode?

Tags: java

I was thinking that it was NOT PRINT since NOT is a logical no. But I am not quite too sure. Can someone please help me?

```
IF first operand > second operand THEN
PRINT question
ELSE
IF first operand<= second operand THEN
NOT PRINT question
```

I was thinking it is something like that but again, I am not too sure.

Comment: Programming is about "what, when and how" should be done. It's not about what should not be done. :) So, you should only keep the first two rows of your pseudocode.

Comment: It's pseudocode--basically, English. Write it however you like. But in this case it's usual just not to include the second `IF` at all.

Comment: Programming is about giving instructions to the machine telling it what to do.  If there is nothing to do, write nothing.

Comment: Oh alright. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed with Konstantin Yovkov. Off to a rocky start in stackoverflow ey @Ansh. Dw keep grinding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write in pseudocode then just write in English:

```
if (first_operand > second_operand){
    print(question)
}
if (first_operand <= second_operand) {
    // if you're not printing the question, then state
    what you wish to print as argument.
    print(answer)
}
```

But it sounds like you haven't grasped the fundamentals of programming. I would suggest you get started with something like [CodeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/learn) where there are videos on various programming paths.